# If $A$ and $B$ are linear operators such that $A(x)=B(x)$ then $x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space. If $A,B:V \longrightarrow V$ are linear operators such that $A(x)=B(x)$ for some $x \in V$, then $x=0$?

Is that true or not? And I couldn't think of a counterexample.

Comment: Well, what if $A=B$?  What if $A$ is the identity map, and $B$ is some other map that happens to fix a non-zero vector?

Comment: Suppose $A$ and $B$ are distinct and both different identity.

Comment: $x\in\ker(A-B)$.

Comment: It's easy to find two different linear maps that happen to fix the same vector.  Just try.

Comment: $V=\mathbb{Z}_2, A=0, B(x)=2x$. Then $A(1)=0=B(1)$.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelHolanda

Comment: $0=A(x)-B(x)=(A-B)(x)$ should ring the bell. A kernel of a linear map. Is it always $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the transformations defined by the matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&5\end{pmatrix}$$ and apply them to the vector

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering the matrix of the transformations A and B as M and M' respectively, A(x)=B(x) means that Mx=M'x -> Mx-M'x=0 -> (M-M')x=0, considering that we can write x in a matrix representation, and as matrices form a Ring with divisors of zero, so there is nothing we can conclude from this. If you want a counter example try thinking about matrices